# How do I install a security certificate in EasyPHP?

Tags: ssl, easyphp

I want to use the cacert.pem certificate from the cURL website so my EasyPHP server can use cURL to retrieve a site using SSL. How do I install it and is this all I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by following the instructions here: http://kb.ucla.edu/articles/how-do-i-use-curl-in-php-on-windows